# How to use Linq to check if string property contains any of string in a list collection

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, list, contains

I have string with comma separated list of emails

```
var emails="a@gmail.com,b@gmail.com,c@gmail.com,d@gmail.com,e@gmail.com,";
var list=new List<string>();
list.Add("c@gmail.com");
list.Add("d@gmail.com");
```

how can I write ling query to find out if string(email) has any email address matching to 
collection(list).

I am using EF and emails string is property in a class and list is independent collection.

Comment: Are you saying that `emails` is actually a property on an entity that you are querying with EF?

Comment: yes @juharr emails is property of on an entity

Comment: Well then you really should consider not storing comma separated lists in your DB as one string, and instead create a proper one-to-many relationship.

Comment: I really can't change the database in my case. This is the requirement.

Comment: It's important to tell us what you tried so far.

Comment: I have used the Fann Solution
var hasMatch = list.Any(item => ","+emails.ToLower().Contains(","+item.ToLower()+","));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This solution uses linq. Because your email addresses are comma separated (and ends in a comma) we can check if Any() of the items in the list are contained by the emails string.  I used ToLower() to make it case insensitive (which email addresses typically are).

```
var hasMatch = list.Any(item => ","+emails.ToLower().Contains(","+item.ToLower()+","));
```

Comment: Thanks @Fann this is the one solution that I can think of.

Answer (score 1):

```
emails.Split(',').Any(e=>list.Contains(e));
```

alternatively:

```
emails.Split(',').Intersect(list).Any();
```

If you are using it to find database records, then you can do this:

```
db.MyTable.Where(l=>list.Any(e=>l.emails.StartsWith(e+",")) ||
list.Any(e=>l.emails.EndsWith(","+e)) ||
list.Any(e=>l.emails.Contains(","+e+",")) ||
list.Any(e=>l.emails==e)
)
```

or you can simplify it with:

```
db.MyTable.Where(l=>list.Any(e=>(","+l.emails+",").Contains(","+e+",")))
```

The 3rd option may perform better if you are looking for the first record as it might use any index you have on emails to quickly locate the record, but it will generate some really big SQL statements if the list is big (Current implementations of SQL LINQ provider unfortunately translates this to a CHARINDEX function instead of LIKE 'email%', but that could change).

The 4th option will generate simpler SQL, and will likely perform better if want to find all the records that match instead of just the first one.

Comment: You will need `emails.Split(new char[]{','}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)` because of the trailing `,` in the email list.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Only if you want to assume that an empty string match isn't valid, which I wouldn't make that assumption.  If you don't want to match an empty string, then don't put an emtpy string in `list`.

Comment: But `string.Contains(text, "")` will always return true, and the email list has a trailing `,` so if you don't remove empty entries after splitting, the result will be true regardless of the contents of `list`.

Comment: @MatthewWatson But I never do `string.Contains(text,"")`.  The first two are `List<string>.Contains(string)` so it is looking for an exact element that matches.  The 3rd (and 4th) weren't there when you first replied, and still don't exhibit the behavior your describe.

Comment: @MatthewWatson `["ABC","DEF",""].Contains("something")` returns false.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it following way

```
emails.Split(',').Any (y => list.Contains (y));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var emailsList = emails.Split(',');
list.Any( x => emailsList.Contains(x));
```

Antoher approach

```
  HashSet<String> emailSet = New HashSet<String>(temp.Split(","));
  list.Any(s => emailSet.Contains(s, StringComparer.Ordinal));
```

Use HashSet - `Contains` works faster (if emails string can be big) and remove duplicates
And comparing stringg in case-sensitive without creating new strings by `ToLower()`

Comment: The `x =` there won't compile.